# Remove view as soon as user delete data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

I got this simplified code

```
class Request extends Component {
 constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.Remove = this.Remove.bind(this)
 }

 componentWillMount(){
    firebase.database().ref('/Users/' + AuthID).orderByChild('UserRequests').on("value", function(snapshot) {
         snapshot.forEach((child) => {
             Name = child.val().Name;
             UserID = child.val().UserID;
             obj = {key: keyIndex++, Name: Name, ID: UserID};
             Requests.push(obj)
         });
         self.setState({Array: Requests});
     });

 }


 //Need to call map func again as soon as user use Remove func and remove data
 RenderUsers = () => {
         return this.state.Array.map((Data) => (
                 <View key={Data.key}>
                      <TouchableHighlight  onPress={() => {
                          this.Remove(Data.ID, Data.Name, Data.key);
                      }}>
                          <Text> Remove </Text>
                      </TouchableHighlight>
                 </View>
            ))
 };

 Remove = (ID, Name, KeyIndex) => {
   this.state.Array.splice(KeyIndex, 1);
   firebase.database().ref('Users/' + AuthID + '/UserRequests/').child(ID).remove();
   //this.RenderUsers();
 };

 render(){
   <View>
        {this.RenderUsers()}
   </View>
 }
}
```

Let's say map function rendered 10 views. As soon as user clicked on a `TouchableHighlight` it removes from Firebase right `View` (request) and it doesn't exist anymore. Unfortunately I can't re-map array after data are deleted. I tried many ways but nothing worked. I thought problem is that I get data in componentWillMount. So it can't get data from Firebase after first mount anymore but if I add Request to database when app is running on that screen it appears immediately. Problem shouldn't be in componentWillMount function.

Comment: Check [Firebase API for `on` events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on). You are only pushing new items to `Requests`. Where do you create it or do you clear contents of it before pushing new items?

Comment: @bennygenel I'm going to check it! I forgot about removing that object from an array. Code is updated. Anyway I still can't get result which I want

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Well it doesn't solve problem. I just copied badly.